# Set M with $|M|=\infty$, nested $\emptyset$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

$M_1=\emptyset$

$M_n=\{M_1,M_2,...,M_{n-1}\}$

If $n\rightarrow\infty$, is $|M_n|=\infty$?

$M_2=\{\emptyset\}$

$|M_2|=1$

is this right?

$M_3=\{\emptyset,\{\emptyset\}\}$

$|M_3|=2$

again is this right?

Can i solve this via induction,

or can i show that there exists a bijection between $\mathbb{N}$ and $M_n$, when $n\rightarrow\infty$

Comment: was is your definition of infinite cardinality?

Comment: If it is not of infinite cardinality, it is of finite cardinality. What would that cardinality be?

Comment: @user251257 do you mean, that my question is illworded and i should rather formulate it in another way?

Comment: Oh sorry for my bad spelling. I meant "What is the definition of infinite cardinality that you know?"

Comment: @user251257 i only know that $\mathbb{N}$ is one of the smallest sets with infinite elements in it. so any set that has less then that, is called finite set. To be honest, i think i simply mean "has M infinite elements in it?" and just formulated it this way.

Comment: the usual definition is "$M$ is not finite", that is by definition "There is no bijection from $\{1, \dotsc, n\}$ into $M$ for any $n\in\mathbb N$. One can show, $M$ is infinite, if there is an injective function from $\mathbb N$ into $M$. Could you define $M$ in a more formal way, without ellipsis? It would make any proof easier to check.

Comment: @user251257 would be a recusive definition of M get me where i want? like $M_1=\{M_2\}$

Comment: I have no idea what $M$ is. You need to know. If it is homework, you should copy the question as exact as possible. Also, you should post what you have tried. Otherwise, your question will be down voted and deleted quite fast.

Comment: @user251257 can you take a look if my question makes now sense?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is rather a very extensive comment.

1. For any $n$ the set $M_n$ is finite, as $|M_n| \le n-1$.
2. Once you have shown that $M_i \ne M_j$ for $1 \le i < j \le n$, you may conclude that $|M_n| = n-1$.
3. Thus, $|M_n|$ does diverge to $\infty$ for $n\to\infty$. However, each set $M_n$ is finite itself.
4. $M_n$ is a popular way to model the natural number $n-1$ in context of set theory.
5. Guess what $\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb N} M_n$ is.

Comment: to 3.: isnt "diverge" the better formulation? or do you mean $\infty$ as a point?

Comment: @saturatedexpo: right, diverge :)

Comment: my guess is, that ($\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb N} M_n$) is equivalent to (my $M_n$ when n goes $\infty$)

Comment: @saturatedexpo: the union is isomorphic to $\mathbb N$. Actually, the union is also by definition the "limit" of $M_n$. Notice that convergence of sets is much more complicated...

Comment: so the union has basicly just "renamed" all numbers of $\mathbb{N}$ to sets.

Comment: @saturatedexpo: Kind of. In logic and set theory, it is called a model. That is, you can compute and work with the sets $M_n$'s like with natural numbers. Natural number is an abstract concept. We don't know if it exists. But, if we accept that sets exist, then so do something that work like natural numbers. (Of course set is also an abstract concept... )

Comment: if you are so kind, can you rename the question to something more fitting? or is it ok? well thanks anyway :)